# Change your password on the Woocommerce Checkout-page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a development and I need that users **already registered on my site**, change their password obligatorily on the woocommerce checkout-page.

I tried the classic solution:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');

function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields)
{
    $fields['account']['account_password'] = array(
      'type' => 'password',
      'required'  => true,
      'label' => __('Pass', 'woocommerce'),
      'placeholder' => _x('Pass', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
      'class' => array('form-row-wide')
  );

    return $fields;
}
```

This mode only works for me when the user is registering, but not for changing their password.

Do you think I should make a `wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );` ? If so, **where would you place the code**?

I need a way to do an `UPDATE` and change `user_pass` from `wp_users` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'wc_checkout_field_update_user_meta' );

   function wc_checkout_field_update_user_meta( $user_id, $data ) { 

     if ( $data['account_password'] ) {   

       update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_password', $data['account_password'] );
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tested it but the checkout throws me an "internal server error" for the field account_password. I believe that `woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta` changes user data from Woocommerce but not from the generic table `wp_users`. I need to change wordpress native `user_pass`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a mix between @Raihan code and Googling´s code but **I can't change `user_pass`**. With this code it dont show "Internal server error" by Woocommerce.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'user_fields_woocommerce_checkout_process' );

function user_fields_woocommerce_checkout_process(){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta',
        'my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta' );
    }
}

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta( $user_id ) {
    if ( $data['account_password'] ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_password', $data['account_password'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably should use `wp_set_password` and not `update_user_meta`